# triggerRef does not work on shallowRef with multi-level object

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I have a shallowRef object

```
const someObject = shallowRef(
  {
    someKey: {
      subKey1: {
        k1: "value1",
        k2: "value2",
      }
    },
    anotherKey: {
      subKey1: {
        k1: "value1",
        k2: "value2",
      }
    }
  }
)
```

And I want to trigger reactive state after update the someObject -
`triggerRef(someObject)`

But there are no changes in child component which uses the someObject. What do I miss?

My expectation was to use lightweight ref and trigger reactive state programmatically only when it is needed.

Comment: Please, provide [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem.